# model.save() returns an invalid output

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I am making a simple test for RESTApi using Node.js, mongodb and express from this article:
[MERN Part I: Building RESTful APIs with Node.js and Express](https://medium.com/weekly-webtips/building-restful-apis-with-node-js-and-express-a9f648219f5b)
but there is an error somewhere in code i can't locate. The author of article used babel but due to some other error i avoided it. Given below are code files:

App.js

```
var routes= require('./src/routes/userRoutes').routes
var express= require("express")
var mongoose=require('mongoose')
var bodyParser=require('body-parser')

const app = express();
const PORT=4001

// SET INDEX PAGE
app.get('/',function(req,res){
    res.send(`Node and express server running on PORT ${PORT}`);
});

// START SERVER
app.listen(PORT,function(){
    console.log(`Your server is running on PORT ${PORT}`);
});

// ESTABLISH ROUTES
routes(app)

// Join Database to API
mongoose.Promise= global.Promise;
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/userdb', {
    useNewUrlParser:true,
    useUnifiedTopology:true
})

// body-parser setup
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended:true}));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
```

userModel.js : I have commented out the "required" to avoid the Validation Error and see what document is being saved in the collection.

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose')
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;
const  UserSchema = new Schema({
    userName:{
        type:String,
        //required:"Enter your name",
    },
    UserID:{
        type:Number,
        //required:"Enter User ID:",
    },
    password:{
        type:String,
        // reequired:"Enter your password?",
    }
});
module.exports={UserSchema}
```

userController.js:

```
var mongoose=require('mongoose')
var UserSchema = require("../models/userModel").UserSchema;
const UserModel= mongoose.model("Users",UserSchema)
const addNewUser = (req,res) => {
    let newUser= new UserModel(req.body);
    newUser.save((err,user) => {
        if(err) res.send(err)
        else res.json(user)
    })
}
module.exports={addNewUser}
```

userRoute.js:

```
var addNewUser = require('../controllers/userController').addNewUser;

const routes = (app) => {
    // create routes for login/signup/view
    app.route('/users')
    .get((req,res)=> res.send("Get request successful"))
    
    app.route('/users/:userID')
    .put((req,res)=>res.send(`Put Request succesful for ${req.params.donationID}`))
    .delete((req,res)=>res.send("delete Request successful"))
    .post(addNewUser);

    app.route('/done')
    .get((req,res)=>{
        res.send("Goodbye");
        process.exit(0);
    });
}
module.exports={routes};
```

Response recieved when POST request with URI:`localhost:4001/users/1?userName=Adnan&UserID=123&password=0000`

```
{
    "_id": "5fd0b07b12615110d420a91b",
    "__v": 0
}
```

Expected Output: User Object in JSON

Comment: On this line: `let newUser= new UserModel(req.body);` you're using `req.body`. But you're not passing the data in the body when making your request, you're passing it in the query string: `req.query`. In the tutorial, they used `req.body` and specifically said, about making the request: _"Make sure the Body you’ve selected “x-www-form-urlencoded”"_

Comment: Thank you, its solved now i didn't understood what it meant before.

Comment: @blex i changed it `req.body` to `req.query` and it worked but i used x-www-form-urlencoded with `req.body` and passing the key-value pairs in body of POST but again it returns the same output

Comment: Haha, it's either you use req.query and you pass the data in the query string as you originally did OR you use req.body and you use an object with key/value pairs in the body

Comment: Try Postman, it would help you a lot when performing these kinds of testing. It helps you set fields manually with a nice GUI.